# How to drop & drag from Outlook?

Tags: filepicker.io

Is there a way to implement drag & drop from Outlook? It's very common that people drag a file from their Outlook. When I drag & drop it into the default widget, it says "Doesn't seem like a valid file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this and it appears that dragging and dropping from outlook to just about any application does not work, due to a lack of functionality on the part of Outlook - see https://superuser.com/questions/441747/dragging-attachments-from-outlook-into-applications.

Unfortunately, it looks like this one is out of our control.